# Determine and adjusting camera zooming level in ios

Tags: ios

I want to determine the camera zooming level in ios. How i adjust zoom level according to my vision like 20/20 , 20/50 etc.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about it, but did you try adding the following code so that default zoom control will be visible?

```
picker.showsCameraControls = YES;
```

Comment: Actually i want to use the camera to magnify the image or text to the set prescription value for 20/20 vision required for efficient reading or viewing. For that purpose i want to know the zooming level adjustment in iOS.